# Purpose of running dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() on UI Thread

Tags: ios

It's quite common to see in real cases that dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() is implemented  on UI Thread. I can not figure out its purpose.

My thinking is since there's only one thread on the UI thread, what's the purpose of dispatch_async?

Take a real example I met days ago here:

Run a "NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval" on the UI thread to update "_scrollView contentOffset"

1 no dispatch: 
setContentOffset get effective until next NSTimer schedule

2 with dispatch :
setContentOffset get effective immediately

Comment: Can you give some context?  Maybe the code *could* be run from a background thread so it's just to be safe.  Otherwise it could just be to delay the code until maybe the layout engine had a time to run.

Comment: I have given an example above

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ... )` forces a block of code to be run asynchronously on the next run loop of the main thread (UI thread). Some code must be run on the UI thread, such as adding/removing widgets from the UI or updating the UI.

`dispatch_async( .. )` is used as to not block the current thread.

Comment: In practice and reality, I found this way could speed up the execution when UI thread is busy with several other tasks, even though it does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                       ^{
                           // perform something on UI
                       });
```

dispatch_async is a low level GCD API (Grand Central Dispatch API). As we know Applications main thread is used to perform any activities on UI like performing animations/ any other UI related stuff, so in the context of doing some work with the UI it is essential that it should have access to main thread and what above GCD API does it provides the same guaranteed access to the main thread for the UI to perform any related operations.

Answer (score 0):

GCD to the main queue is usually done from a background queue to signal that some background processing has finished. For example

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),^{
    // Here you are doing a very expensive operation which will take let say 5 secs. And after 5 sec you will got your result. Let say

    int output = //calculated result.

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [[self myLable] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", output]];     
    });
});
```

In this case, we are doing a lengthy calculation on a background queue to not to block the main thread. And after getting the result we need to update the UI. `UIKit` should not be accessed from any other thread, it should be accessed from `main thread` to avoid the race condition and prevent the crashing during accessing `UIKit`. So here we are using `dispatch_async` to give a chance to the main thread to work by `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use it when inside another `dispatch_async`(background, non-UI thread) - when I do something like computation or just anything that can run on a background thread **and then** I want to "come back" and update the UI accordingly, `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...)` returns me back on UI thread and thus I can update the UI. Otherwise if I'd stay on the background thread in the first `dispatch_async`, no changes would be made on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the code "dispatch_async" is not on  main thread, dispatch_get_main_queue guarantee the code in the block runs on main thread.

it likes performselectonmainthread,